# Case sensitive permissions in android?

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

Are permissions' names case sensitive ? This works fine:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

and that one doesn't:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

The problem is though, that the latter was automatically created by Android Studio 1.2 when I typed R and pressed enter. Am I missing something or it's a Android Studio's bug?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the bug, but I am sure that intents and permissions are case sensitive.